# Detect 4 finger scrolling in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Is there a way to write an event listener for the 4 finger swipe mac pad gesture?  I want to incorporate multiple lateral dashboards on my web page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 4 finger swipes are reserved for the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe modernizr does this: http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

try to hammerjs

you can select hou many pointeras to use an option

http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @lv0gun9 and @Jersh
You can use

1. http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/
2. http://modernizr.com/

But if you are planning to get this usable on a iPad that won't be possible as that gesture is reserved for iOS.